# Programmatically grab screenshots in OSX and convert to OpenCV Mat

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, screenshot

I'm trying to capture the Mac OS X display screen and convert it to OpenCV `Mat` in C++.

I have written the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main (int argc, char * const argv[])
{
    size_t width = CGDisplayPixelsWide(CGMainDisplayID());
    size_t height = CGDisplayPixelsHigh(CGMainDisplayID());

    Mat im(cv::Size(width,height), CV_8UC4);
    Mat bgrim(cv::Size(width,height), CV_8UC3);
    Mat resizedim(cv::Size(width,height), CV_8UC3);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(
                                                    im.data, im.cols, im.rows,
                                                    8, im.step[0],
                                                    colorSpace,    kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast|kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault);

    while (true)
    {
        CGImageRef imageRef = CGDisplayCreateImage(CGMainDisplayID());
        CGContextDrawImage(contextRef,
                           CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height),
                           imageRef);
        cvtColor(im, bgrim, CV_RGBA2BGR);
        resize(bgrim, resizedim,cv::Size(),0.5,0.5);
        imshow("test", resizedim);
        cvWaitKey(10);
        CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    }

//    CGContextRelease(contextRef);
//    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return 0;
}
```

and then, the result is here.

[image: result]

I had expected my actual current display would be captured, but only the back wallpaper was captured actually.

Would you know any solution?
I would appreciate if you could reply me.

Answer (score 0):

It was turned out that the problem was simply due to the protect by OSX catalina.
So it should be resolved only by providing permission to the program for accessing the screen.
Sorry for this trivial question.